# Autoincremento em campo numérico no MongoDb (não é o ID)

Tags: mongoose

Olá, tenho dificuldade para utilizar uma função de autoincremento em um campo numérico no *Mongodb* (não é ID).
O código é em *nodeJs* com *mongoose* e não uso plugin mongoose-autosequence etc.
A estrutura do projeto é *route-controller-model.*
A rota passa o `req.body` para o controller;
O Controller é cria o documento no banco;
O model contem somente o Schema. A função `nextval` é usada no controller, que deverá obter um novo número para o campo numero antes de criar o documento.

A função `nextVal` vai na coleção counters, incrementa 1 ao sequence e retornar o valor do campo (arquivo nextVal.js):

```
import { db } from '../models/index.js';
const Counter = db.counterModel;

const nextVal = async (seqName) => {
  var seqDoc = await Counter.findAndModify({
    query: { _id: seqName },
    update: { $inc: { sequence_value: 1 } },
    new: true
  });
  return seqDoc.sequence_value;
};
export default { nextVal };
```

O controller recebe o `req.body` e persiste na coleção pedido. Uso async function, mas não está aceitando a `nextVal()`. O erro diz que `nextVal` não é function:

```
import { db } from '../models/index.js';
import nextVal from './nextVal.js';
const Pedido = db.pedidoModel;

const create = async (req, res) => {
  // Cria um Pedido com itens de pedido
  const pedido = new Pedido({
    numero: nextVal('pedido'),
    descricao: req.body.descricao,
    dped: Date.now()
  });

  // Save pedido in the database
  Pedido.create(pedido, (err, data) => {
    if (err)
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Erro ao criar o pedido."
      });
    else res.send(data);
  });
};
```

O model:

```
export default (mongoose) => {

  const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    numero: { type: Number, required: false },
    descricao: { type: String, required: false },
    dped: { type: Date, required: false, default: Date.now }
  });

  schema.method('toJSON', function () {
    const { __v, _id, ...object } = this.toObject();
    object.id = _id;
    return object;
  });

  const pedidoModel = mongoose.model('pedido', schema, 'pedido');
  return pedidoModel;
};
```

Pesquisei outras perguntas semelhantes, mas não consegui aplicar no meu caso. Elas usam pre-save, ou fazem insert direto no *db.colecao* no *mongodb*. Peço ajuda por favor, de como usar a função no controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

segue a solução para os 2 problemas:

1. O mongoose não aceita o FinfAndModify; devo substituir pelo FindAndUpdate (com os devidos ajustes de parâmetros);
2. Quanto a definição de uso da função nextVal():

2.1 A função deve ser async / await (código abaixo após as respostas). Eu coloquei a função no escopo do controller (ao invés de importar);
2.2 A chamada da função deve ser precedida de await (código abaixo após função).

A função nexVal() ficou assim, declarada e utilizada dentro do controller:

const Counter = db.counterModel;

async function nextVal(seqName) {
var seqDoc = await Counter.findAndUpdate(
{ _id: seqName },
{ $inc: { sequence_value: 1 } },
{ new: true }
);
return seqDoc.sequence_value;
};

e a chamada à função ficou assim:

const create = async (req, res) => {
// Cria um Pedido com itens de pedido
const pedido = new Pedido({
numero: await nextVal('pedido'),
descricao: req.body.descricao,
dped: Date.now()
});

Vou fechar essa question.